# How to debug NLog Database target

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

I have an NLog config that I wish was writing logs to MS SQL.

```
  <targets>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss}|${level}|${stacktrace}|${message}"/>
    <target xsi:type="Database"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;F:\...\Logging.mdf\&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
            commandType="StoredProcedure"
            commandText="[dbo].[int_Log]"
            name="database">
      <parameter name="@TransactionId" layout="transaction-id"/>
      <parameter name="@SectionId" layout="section-id"/>
      <parameter name="@UserId" layout="user-id"/>
      <parameter name="@CompanyCode" layout="company-code"/>
      <parameter name="@CategoryId" layout="category-id"/>
      <parameter name="@Data" layout="data"/>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!--<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

This *should* by invoking the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE int_Log
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TransactionId VARCHAR(50),
    @SectionId VARCHAR(50),
    @UserId VARCHAR(50),
    @CompanyCode VARCHAR(50),
    @CategoryId VARCHAR(50),
    @Data VARCHAR(5000)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Logs]
           ([TransactionId]
           ,[SectionId]
           ,[UserId]
           ,[CompanyCode]
           ,[CategoryID]
           ,[Data]
           ,[Id])
     VALUES
           (@TransactionId,
           @SectionId,
           @UserId,
           @CompanyCode,
           @CategoryId,
           @Data,
           NEWID())
END
```

However, there aren't any new rows appearing in in the table.  How do I go about debugging this?  The problem with the XML config is that it seems to either work, or not.

Answer (score 5):

Instructions for debug output are [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging).

To log out to the console, just add `internalLogToConsole="true"` to the `<nlog>` element, i.e.:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      internalLogToConsole="true">
```